# AJAX function gives void, fread (php) output to html div

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is a PHP function that reads first the title then the content of a txt file that has been uploaded,

```
<?php
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$output = "";
if ($q !== "") {
    $bestand = fopen("Blogs.txt", "r");
    if (!$bestand) {
        echo "Kon geen bestand openen";
    }
    while (!feof($bestand)) {
        $blog = fgets($bestand);
        $blog = explode(",", $blog);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($blog as $key) {
            $i++;
            if ($i % 2 == 0) {
                $output = $key;
            }
            elseif (!$i % 2 == 0) {
                $Blogname = fopen("Blogs/$key", "r");
                $Blogtext = fread($Blogname, filesize("Blogs/$key"));
                $output = $Blogtext;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($bestand);
}
?>
```

but then i wanted to have it show up in html instead of php so i search solution and found AJAX but have been struggling for hours on why it doesn't work

```
    function Getblog() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "Blogreader.php?q=" + str, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var para = document.createElement("div");
            var t = document.createElement(this.responseText);
            para.appendChild(t);
            document.getElementById("BlogDiv").appendChild(para);
        }
    };
}
```

This is the Javascript code that gives a void function.
What i want it to do is make a DIV of the output of a the php function

```
<a> <input type="button" onclick="Getblog()"></a>
<div id="BlogDiv"></div>
```

And this is the refresh button and the div where they are going to be showed

Comment: of course it won't work... for one: you are specifying a param `q` value of `str` but where is `str` defined, within your function `Getblog`?.... and what @Quentin said.

Comment: "This is the Javascript code that gives a void function" — What does "gives a void function" mean? That isn't standard JavaScript terminology. A void function in other languages is one that doesn't have a return value: But (a) JavaScript functions cannot not have a return value (if there is no return statement, then they return `undefined`, which is a value) and (b) You aren't looking at the return value anyway.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have an input inside an anchor.

Comment: im still new to programming  so i'm not sure about the anchor because i saw it somewhere and i quess i remembered something wrong. but it does work. but the void function, it said it when i referred to it when i typed in the onclick

Comment: i changed the anchor to a button and still doesnt work, and the thing about str is i saw on w3schools that its said that that was the id, so i think i read that wrong. so i deleted str

Comment: @Cinition no... DO NOT delete... you need to pass `str` as your `$_GET` param... as you are reading the said param in your PHP **AND** subsequently, your execution *depends* on that param on the PHP side; you need to define it in your JavaScript function! Once you have corrected that, please post any **error(s)** you may be getting!

Comment: @Cinition as your PHP code is not making use of the value of `$q` (other than checking it **`!= ""`**), change `xmlhttp.open("GET", "Blogreader.php?q=" + str, true);` to `xmlhttp.open("GET", "Blogreader.php?q=dummyVal", true);` and see what happens (in terms of errors etc.)

Comment: i changed it to `xmlhttp.open("GET", "Blogreader.php?q=dummyVal", true);` and changed `document.createElement(this.responseText);` to `document.createTextNode(this.responseText);` . and it gives back saying that it failed to open stream

Comment: Now the only problem i have is that the text form for the titel doesn't send to php.